# Angular 2 Azure Media Services Video Playback

Tags: html, azure, angular, video

I cannot play an Azure Media Services video using Angular. I have a simple html page that works:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link href="//amp.azure.net/libs/amp/1.3.0/skins/amp-default/azuremediaplayer.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="//amp.azure.net/libs/amp/1.3.0/azuremediaplayer.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<video id="azuremediaplayer" class="azuremediaplayer amp-default-skin amp-big-play-centered" controls autoplay width="640" height="400" poster="" data-setup='{"nativeControlsForTouch": false}' tabindex="0">
        <source src="http://amssamples.streaming.mediaservices.windows.net/91492735-c523-432b-ba01-faba6c2206a2/AzureMediaServicesPromo.ism/manifest" type="application/vnd.ms-sstr+xml" />
        <p class="amp-no-js">To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a web browser that supports HTML5 video</p>
</video>
</body>
</html>
```

But when I add the exact same video tag to an Angular component, it is just a block box that doesn't play my video.

I added the following to my index.html page:

```
<link href="//amp.azure.net/libs/amp/1.3.0/skins/amp-default/azuremediaplayer.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="//amp.azure.net/libs/amp/1.3.0/azuremediaplayer.min.js"></script>
```

And I added the video tag to my component html page:

```
<video id="azuremediaplayer" class="azuremediaplayer amp-default-skin amp-big-play-centered" controls autoplay width="640" height="400" poster="" data-setup='{"nativeControlsForTouch": false}' tabindex="0">
        <source src="http://amssamples.streaming.mediaservices.windows.net/91492735-c523-432b-ba01-faba6c2206a2/AzureMediaServicesPromo.ism/manifest" type="application/vnd.ms-sstr+xml" />
        <p class="amp-no-js">To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a web browser that supports HTML5 video</p>
</video>
```

It's the simplest possible setup, with only one module and one component, and nothing else on the page. I created the project using Angular's latest quickstart sample, so I should have the latest packages. What am I missing?

Comment: your standalone sample does not work for me, and `type="application/vnd.ms-sstr+xml"` is not a valid media type for HTML5 video

Comment: It is certainly a valid format for Azure Media Services media player. Check out the quickstart at the Azure Media Player: https://amp.azure.net/libs/amp/latest/docs/

Comment: @Offbeatmammal as far as the standalone sample not working, if you just save the html to a file and try to load it in a browser, it does not work. But if you load the page using a web server, I did it with Kestrel, it loads just fine as is.

Answer (score 5):

I found the answer to this. I needed to download the typescript definitions file from Microsoft: https://amp.azure.net/libs/amp/latest/docs/

I put this in my typings folder and added a reference path to my video module:

```
/// <reference path="../../typings/azuremediaplayer.d.ts" />
```

You still need to add the azure media player lib files to your index.html:

```
<link href="//amp.azure.net/libs/amp/1.8.0/skins/amp-default/azuremediaplayer.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="//amp.azure.net/libs/amp/1.8.0/azuremediaplayer.min.js"></script>
```

I have a very simple component that only displays the video.

The html:

```
<video 
    id="vid1" 
    class="azuremediaplayer amp-default-skin" 
    autoplay controls width="640" height="400" 
    poster="poster.jpg" >
    <p class="amp-no-js">
        To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a web browser that supports HTML5 video
    </p>
</video>
```

The component code:

```
import { Component, ElementRef, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'my-azure-media-player',
    templateUrl: 'azure-media-player.component.html'
})
export class AzureMediaPlayerComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(private elRef: ElementRef) {}

    ngOnInit(): void {

        var myPlayer = amp('vid1');
        console.log(myPlayer.currentTechName());
        myPlayer.autoplay(true);
        myPlayer.controls(true);
        myPlayer.src({
            type: "application/vnd.ms-sstr+xml",
            src: "//amssamples.streaming.mediaservices.windows.net/91492735-c523-432b-ba01-faba6c2206a2/AzureMediaServicesPromo.ism/manifest"
        });

    }
}
```

From here you can play with the settings.

Comment: Remember to update the versions in the import of script and css, it will save you some trouble.

Comment: current version is 2.3.4 http://amp.azure.net/libs/amp/latest/docs/changelog.html